# How to set MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute in Drupal way?

Tags: mysql, pdo, drupal, drupal-7, shared-hosting

I have site on D7 / Bluehost which was throwing me an error that said:

> "cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active"

and

> "you may enable query buffering by setting the
>   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute"

So, in the emergency I add this line to database.inc (line 306) and worked:

```
$this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

So, rigth now the site is running fine, but I don't know how to fix this problem the Drupal Way. I know it's not good to modify core or a module.

I don't know how to set an attribute to a PDO connection without modifying core or modules.

Do you know an elegant solution?